# Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'. in JS map

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I've been looking for a while here in StackOverflow and through Google, but couldn't really find a solution to my issue. So here it goes.

I have an array of elements in the DOM which I get through a `@ViewChildren('labelSquare') public labelIcon: QueryList<HTMLSpanElement>;` decorator. In the HTML I have the following to bind it:

```
 <span class="status-item" *ngFor="let status of statusList">
     <div *ngIf="status.state !== 'Starting' &&
                 status.state !== 'Stopping' &&
                 status.state !== 'Synchronising' &&
                 status.state !== 'EmergencyStop'"
     >
       <div class="status">
         <span #labelSquare class="status-square fas fa-square {{ status.state }}"></span>
         <span class="status-name">{{ status.text }}</span>
       </div>
     </div>
 </span>
```

I get an array of 58 span elements from this, and now want to append a border that has a 10% darker color than it's current background. Therefore, I'm using a `map` for this:

```
if (this.labelIcon) {
     this.labelIcon.map((icon: HTMLSpanElement) => {
         const element = window.getComputedStyle(icon);
         icon.setAttribute('style', `border: 1px solid ${ColorUtil.darkenBorderFromBackground(element.color)}`);
     });
 }
```

My `ColorUtil.darkenBorderFromBackground()` simply returns `return darken(${backgroundColor}, 10%)`; (uses template string, couldn't figure out how to format here in StackOverflow.

My issue is now that I get a `TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I think you can just use `getComputedStyle()` without the `window.` prefix.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you `console.log()` the `icon` variable into the console and make sure its a DOMElement.

Comment: Running a `console.log` of that I get the following:

`ElementRef {nativeElement: span.AlarmCritical.fa-square.fas.status-square}

nativeElement: span.AlarmCritical.fa-square.fas.status-square

__proto__: ElementRef`

Comment: Ah that's right, Angular gives an ElementRef not a DOM Element. You should replace `icon` with `icon.nativeElement`. `nativeElement` holds a reference to the DOM Element which we need

Comment: Amazing, that worked like a charm! Thank you very much! Do you want to post it as an answer for points?

Comment: Amazing, will do, so you can mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular returns an [`ElementRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) not a DOM element.

`ElementRef` has a property called `nativeElement` which refers to the DOM element. So change `icon` for `icon.nativeElement` inside the `window.getComputedStyle()`

Be aware that your typescript interface also needs to change inside the map method.

E.g.

```
if (this.labelIcon) {
 this.labelIcon.map((icon: ElementRef) => { // Not sure if ElementRef is a valid interface in Angular
     const element = window.getComputedStyle(icon.nativeElement);
     icon.setAttribute('style', `border: 1px solid ${ColorUtil.darkenBorderFromBackground(element.color)}`);
 });
}
```